# How to find position of an ngram in a sentence?

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk, n-gram

**Is there a way to find the first position of an ngram in a sentence?**

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> hyp = ['he', 'read', 'the', 'book', 'because', 'he', 'was', 'interested', 'in', 'world', 'history']
>>> position_of_ngram(('the', 'book'), hyp)
2
```

Currently, I'm using some string hacks:

```
>>> " ".join(hyp)[:" ".join(hyp).index(" ".join(('the', 'book')))].count(' ')
2
```

But **is there a way to do it without silly string conversions?** If so, is that a faster way compared to the "string/regex hack"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to loop over the slices of the words list :

```
>>> def position_of_ngram(words,hyp):
...     lenght=len(words)
...     for i,sublist in enumerate((hyp[i:i+lenght] for i in range(len(hyp)))):
...         if words==sublist:
...            return i
...     return None
```

DEMO:

```
>>> position_of_ngram(['the', 'book'],hyp)
2
>>> 
>>> position_of_ngram(['because', 'he'],hyp)
4
```

Comment: any idea whether that's faster than `str` or `re` methods?

Comment: @alvas Surely it's better than a string based approach because in that case you need to first concatenate the list then search and split or ... .  But in this case you just need to loop over the slices which in based case its complexity is O(1). If you are dealing with large lists you can use `itertools.islice` for splitting your list, which returns an iterator instead of list which is more optimized in terms of memory use.

Comment: Thanks, it works with some tweaks, note that `tuple(x) != list(x)`. So when checking `words == sublist`, there's a need to cast either the tuple to the list or vice versa or cast both to list/tuple.

Comment: @alvas Yep, I forget to mentioned that you need to pass the words as a list.

Answer (score 3):

Why bother searching yourself? This is what the list method `index()` is for:

```
def ngram_index(words, ngram):
    return list(nltk.ngrams(words, len(ngram))).index(tuple(ngram))
```

Answer (score 2):

From @Kasramvd solution, here's a one-liner answer that uses NLTK's `ngrams()` function:

```
from nltk import ngrams
def position_of_ngram(ngram,sentence):
    return next(i for i, ng in enumerate(ngrams(sentence, len(ngram))) if ng == ngram)
```

Comment: That's a better approach. ;-)